# Memory-efficient way to build giant block identity matrices?

Tags: r, for-loop, memory, matrix, sparse-matrix

In R, I'm trying to row-bind several identity matrices into 1 giant matrix using the code below:

```
>     X <- 4
>     Y <- 3
>     block1 <- diag(X)   
>     for(x in 2:Y) {
>     block1 <- cbind(block1,diag(X))   
>        }
```

Should look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1     0     0     0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     1     0     0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     0     1     0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0     0     0     1
```

I feel like there is a cleaner and less memory taxing way to do this.  Truth is my X is in the several thousands and Y is in the 20s so generating the matrix 'from scratch' without using these replacements in the for-loop would be preferred because I'm getting memory blockages.  I tried looking at `bdiag()` in the `Matrix` package but that function isn't exactly what I want.

So is there a function that would do this 'from scratch'?

**EDIT:**

Users were kind enough to suggest I look into 'sparse Matrices.'  I came across the `SparseM` package and am 99% there.  I simply use the `as.matrix.csr` function to convert my matrices into `CSR` format and together with both `cbind.matrix.csr` and `rbind.matrix.csr` I can efficiently get all the matrices I need.  Now the issue is when I try to use it in a Linear Programming solver (`Rsymphony`) I have to use `as.matrix()` to convert the CSR matrix back to normal and it's still giving me a memory issue.

Comment: Have you looked at the google search results for 'storing sparse matrix'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @OChristiaanse suggests, a sparse matrix may be the way to go.  You could try this short call and see if it works for you.

```
library(Matrix)
do.call(cBind, replicate(Y, Diagonal(X)))
4 x 12 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] 1 . . . 1 . . . 1 . . .
[2,] . 1 . . . 1 . . . 1 . .
[3,] . . 1 . . . 1 . . . 1 .
[4,] . . . 1 . . . 1 . . . 1
```

Seeing how you are also using non-sparse data (i.e. not zeros/ones) and have memory issues, you may want to look in to the `bigmemory` package.  With these objects, you can use filebacking and have objects bigger than available memory.

**EDIT**

After speaking with the `bigmemory` maintainer I have learned you can install it for Windows.  It is not on CRAN because the `BH` package (which it depends on) generates a warning from the C++ boost library.  To install it on Windows, you need to install [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools) and then install from the github repo.

```
devtools::install_github("kaneplusplus/bigmemory")
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I tried doing this method, then had issues when I wanted to column-bind this to another matrix (of all zeros), and there are other non-zero matrices that I need to bind this to.

Comment: is bigmemory available for windows?  I'm looking on its CRAN page and it says the Windows binaries aren't available.  'bigmemory.sri' is available is that the same thing?

Comment: Ah, that is unfortunate.  Yes, it is currently only for Linux right now.  I am not sure at the moment what the reason behind that is.  I will need to think above some other memory saving approaches unless someone else jumps in.

Comment: @gtnbz2nite, see my edit regarding how to get `bigmemory` on windows.  Let me know how it works out :)

Comment: Awesome thanks for going the extra mile it's appreciate! I'll get back to you

Comment: alright sorry that took some time but I finally was able to take advantage of bigmemory and create my matrix no problem.  Now the problem is I want to use this matrix in a function, but it looks like I'm getting an error that the number of indicies is greater than R's limit of (2^31-1).  Tried looking for a solution but not getting anywhere except this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640836/max-length-for-a-vector-in-r

Comment: @gtnbz2nite I am glad you managed to create the matrix.  However, I would need more information to try and troubleshoot that problem.  The only guess at the moment is making sure your are using a recent 64-bit R version (>3.0).  I suggest opening a new question with the new function you are trying to use on this large matrix and then I could be of more help.  Also, if this answer has solved your initial question, please accept it so it can be marked as closed.