# "Too many indices" big matrix vector length issue in R

Tags: r, memory, 64-bit, linear-programming

Hello and thanks in advance.  I'm using Rx64 version 3.1.2 on a Windows Server and have a file-backed big matrix generated from the package `bigmemory` that I'm trying to use in a linear programming problem.  The matrix is 7062 rows by 364520 columns for a total of 2574240240 entries (of integers).

When I run the line for the linear program, I get the following error:

```
Error in GetElements.bm(x, i, j) : 
  Too many indices (>2^31-1) for extraction.
```

That number, 2147483647, from what I read is the maximum number of entries R allows for any object even on 64-bit processes.  I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640836/max-length-for-a-vector-in-r) that I can use the 'experimental version' of R to get around this but I was hoping there's a recently available solution.  I have supporting output below to confirm my R  version:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2014                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        66913                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet 

> Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")
[1] "/x64"
```

Comment: Long vectors are supported in R since version 3, so perhaps the issue lies with bigmemory.

Comment: The error is hard-coded into bigmemory.cpp: http://goo.gl/QYQfga

Comment: @James so if I edit bigmemory.cpp and remove all mention of that hard-coded error will it solve the problem?

Comment: It *might*. I would suggest emailing the package author for his views.

Comment: Alright will do, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best if you could also provide the 'line for the linear program' but my comment is too long to put above.

@James is correct that 32-bit is hard-coded in to `bigmemory` at the moment.  After glancing at the source on [github](http://github.com/kaneplusplus/bigmemory) I see the author did remove the constraint and you can download that newest version with:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("kaneplusplus/bigmemory")
```

Without that limitation I believe you will still have a problem.  If I assume correctly, you are also using the complementary package `bigalgebra`.  There is a way to use 64-bit with `bigalgebra` by reintstalling the downloaded tar ball and installing with:

```
REFBLAS=1 R CMD INSTALL bigalgebra_0.8.4.tar.gz
```

**NOTE** - the functions available for 64-bit are very limited currently and will be slower than the non-64-bit versions because of the currently workarounds.

I have been in contact with the original author and I am in the process of updating the packages to utilize `RcppArmadillo` which will provide a cleaner interface and deal with the 64-bit problem.  This is currently in progress at my fork of the package on my [github account](http://github.com/cdeterman/bigalgebra).

Comment: following the advice of 'James' I contacted the author of bigmemory and he did in fact make the change.  Also I'm not using bigalgebra, I'm actually using the Rsymphony package and the Rsymphony_solve_LP function.  I can edit my question with more details but this might be worth an entire new question...

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is basically divide and conquer, meaning splitting your matrix and do as many steps (more) as necessary to reach your goal.