# Linear Programming with Big Matrix - Still having memory problems

Tags: r, memory-management, matrix, linear-programming

Hello everyone and thanks in advance!  I've had a bit of an interesting journey with this problem.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836410/too-many-indices-big-matrix-vector-length-issue-in-r) I figured out how to create a file-backed big matrix using the `bigmemory` package.  This 7062 row by 364520 column matrix is the constraint matrix in a linear programming problem I'm trying to solve using the `Rsymphony` package.  The code is below and the constraint matrix is called `mat` :

```
Rsymph <- Rsymphony_solve_LP(obj
                             ,mat[1:nrow(mat),1:ncol(mat)]
                             ,dir
                             ,rhs
                             ,types="B",max=F, write_lp=T)
```

Unfortunately when I run this, `Rsymphony` tries bringing the file-backed matrix into memory and I don't have enough RAM.  The only reason why I even created the big matrix with `bigmemory` in the first place was to use as little RAM as possible.  Is there any way I can with this code or using another linear programming function complete this with the amount of memory I have available?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was my concern before.  By running `mat[...]` you are converting the `big.matrix` in to a regular `matrix`.  The function will need to be rewritten so it is compatible with `big.matrix` objects.  If you look at the source code for `R_symphony_solve_LP` you will find the following call:

```
out <- .C("R_symphony_solve",
          as.integer(nc),
          as.integer(nr),
          as.integer(mat$matbeg),
          as.integer(mat$matind),
          as.double(mat$values),
          as.double(col_lb),
          as.double(col_ub),
          as.integer(int),
          if(max) as.double(-obj) else as.double(obj),
          obj2 = double(nc),
          as.character(paste(row_sense, collapse = "")),
          as.double(rhs),
          double(),
          objval = double(1L),
          solution = double(nc),
          status = integer(1L),
          verbosity = as.integer(verbosity),
          time_limit = as.integer(time_limit),
          node_limit = as.integer(node_limit),
          gap_limit = as.double(gap_limit),
          first_feasible = as.integer(first_feasible),
          write_lp = as.integer(write_lp),
          write_mps = as.integer(write_mps))
```

This C function will need to be rewritten for it to be compatible with `big.matrix` objects.  If the use of this function is critically important to you, there are some examples of how to access `big.matrix` objects on the Rcpp Gallery website using [Rcpp](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpp/) and [RcppArmadillo](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpparmadillo/).  I am sorry to say there is no easy solution beyond this right now.  You either need to get more RAM or start writing some more code.

Comment: thanks for all your guidance you've been like a shepherd through all this lol I'll check your resources out, thanks!.