# Long Vector Linear Programming in R?

Tags: python, r, linear-programming, large-data

Hello and thanks in advance.  Fresh off the heels of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841813/linear-programming-with-big-matrix-still-having-memory-problems) I acquired some more RAM and now have enough memory to fit all the matrices I need to run a linear programming solver.  Now the problem is none of the Linear Programming packages in R seem to support long vectors (ie large matrices).

I've tried functions `Rsymphony_solve_LP`, `Rglpk_solve_LP` and `lp` from packages `Rsymphony`, `Rglpk`, and `lpSolve` respectively.  All report a similar error to the one below:

```
Error in rbind(const.mat, const.dir.num, const.rhs) : 
  long vectors not supported yet: bind.c:1544
```

I also have my code below in case that helps...the constraint matrix `mat` is my big matrix (7062 rows by 364520 columns) created using the package `bigmemory`.  When I run this this line the matrix is pulled into memory and then after a while the errors show.

```
Rsymph <- Rsymphony_solve_LP(obj,mat[1:nrow(mat),1:ncol(mat)],dir,rhs,types=types,max=max, write_lp=T)
```

I'm guessing this is a hard-coded error in each of the three functions?  Is there currently a linear programming solver in R or even Python that supports long vectors?  Should I contact the package maintainers or just edit the code myself?  Thanks!

Comment: Is your constraint matrix sparse? If so, you should specify them sparsely using, e.g., `set.row` from lpSolveAPI. If it's not sparse, then I'd imagine you'll having trouble solving an LP that large anyways.

Comment: @josilber It's not sparse...but you're suggesting I might have some luck turning it into a sparse matrix?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if the constraint matrix is mostly non-zero then solving an LP of that size is going to be computationally challenging even if you get it into the solver. If the constraint matrix is mostly 0 you should definitely use LP packages' mechanisms for inputting sparse matrices.

Comment: @josilber There's a decent amount of non-zero values in there, but the decision variables is going to be a binary type so it should be doable...I'll look more into using sparse Matrices...is there a specific package that works better or an example of using sparse matrix syntax you can point to?  thanks!

Comment: @josilber, I have been able to do this with a 7038x196280 constraint matrix.  You can see the original question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136608/constrained-assignment-problem-linear-programming-genetic-algorithm-etc), it's a mutlifacility problem.  I initially did try this with a genetic algorithm but I don't have much experience in that.  I feel like this should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `lpSolveAPI` can solve long-vector linear programming problems.  You have to first start my declaring a Linear Programming object, then add the constraints:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

#Generate Linear Programming Object
lprec <- make.lp(nrow = 0 # Number of Constraints
                 , ncol = ncol(mat) # Number of Decision Variables
)

#Set Objective Function to Minimize
set.objfn(lprec, obj)

#Add Constraints
#Note Direction and RHS is included along with Constraint Value
for(i in 1:nrow(mat) ){
  add.constraint(lprec,mat[i,], dir[i], rhs[i])
  print(i)
}

#Set Decision Variable Type
set.type(lprec, c(1:ncol(mat)), type = c("binary"))

#Solve Model
solve(lprec)

#Obtain Solutions
get.total.iter(lprec)
get.objective(lprec)
get.variables(lprec)
```

There's a good introduction to this package [here](http://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/web/packages/lpSolveAPI/vignettes/lpSolveAPI.pdf).