# Melting large dataframes--is there a practical size limit for reshape2's melt?

Tags: r, large-data, melt

#### The problem

I am trying to reshape a survey dataset loaded into a dataframe with about 11k variables and 2k rows into a long(er) format, in order to do some analysis on variables that resulted from looped questions. I have not been able to figure out a way to get around memory allocation errors.

Am I hitting the practical size limit for using melt on dataframes (with about 28MB in CSV-format)? Is there a different way to use melt, or would you use a different function/library for this purpose?

#### What I've tried so far

I've tried using reshape2's melt function, which should be straightforward but gives a memory error immediately ("cannot allocate vector of size...").

Then I tried breaking up the looped variables into chunks, in order to get many smaller dataframes to melt and then re-constitute. That gives me similar errors (with smaller sizes that cannot be allocated).

For reference, my data has an identifier field ("SbjNum"), a number of variables that only occur once (about 1900), and 99 variables that occur 100 times each (with a prefix of "I_X_I_Y", where X and Y identify loops)--and should be molten into rows corresponding to unique X and Y.

Just using melt naively looked like this:

```
molten <- melt(data, id.vars = c("SbjNum"))
```

The chunking I've tried so far looks like this:

```
#all variable names produced by the loops
loops <- names(data)[grep("I_\\d{1,2}_I_\\d{1,2}",names(data))] 

#setting number of desired chunks
nloopvars <- length(loops)
nchunks <- 100

#make nchunks indexers to subset my data
chunks <- lapply(#indices of loops split into nchunks groups
                 split(1:nloopvars, sort(1:nloopvars%%nchunks)), 
                 function(v){loops[v]}
                 )

#melt little subsets of the data       
molten <- lapply(chunks,
                    function(x){
                      # take only identifier and a subset of loop vars
                      df <- data[c("SbjNum", x)] 
                      # melt the loop vars
                      return(melt(df, id.vars = "SbjNum"))
                      }
                    )
```

EDIT: after terminating and restarting R as well as clearing my workspace several different ways, approach #2 now works.

Comment: Hi Joran, I always thought gather is just a wrapper for melt? I just tried converting the whole thing into a data.table and that, too, gives a vector allocation error--any suggestions?

Comment: Melting can lead to a large number of rows and might take you past this R limit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640836/max-length-for-a-vector-in-r I would be surprised if a 28 MB file took you there, though, based on using data.table::melt. Maybe you can post a reproducible example to illustrate the issue?

Comment: Thanks for that, Frank--when I tried to just create some data to share, R started giving me memory errors; after a restart of everything the chunked approach is now working. I suspect there is some Windows data management issue, and would love to know what happened but probably never will...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077668/what-methods-can-we-use-to-reshape-very-large-data-sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After terminating and restarting R, and clearing the workspace several times, my own "chunking" approach is now working (see question)--I recommend trying this in case anyone else has similar issues.

[There is still a question of up to what size melting makes sense, but I can live without knowing that answer for now.]

Comment: I think you don't need to make df, fwiw, something like `melt(data, id="SbjNum", measure.vars = x)`... oh, looks like the data.table version is needed for that.