# Maximum length of a vector in R is only 349?

Tags: r, vector, variable-length

I would like to use a very long vector in R, but it seems that when I create a vector, the maximum length/number of values in the vector is 349. See below for code for `vector1` and `vector2`. I can create `vector1` with 349 values without a problem, but `vector2`, which contains 350 values, throws `+` on the next line, as if I forgot to use a closing `"` or `)`.

I read this post:
[Max Length for a Vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640836/max-length-for-a-vector-in-r), but that is completely different from my experience.

Am I missing something? Can anyone help, please?

**Code**

```
 vector1 <- c("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6", "value7", "value8", "value9", "value10", "value11", "value12", "value13", "value14", "value15", "value16", "value17", "value18", "value19", "value20", "value21", "value22", "value23", "value24", "value25", "value26", "value27", "value28", "value29", "value30", "value31", "value32", "value33", "value34", "value35", "value36", "value37", "value38", "value39", "value40", "value41", "value42", "value43", "value44", "value45", "value46", "value47", "value48", "value49", "value50", "value51", "value52", "value53", "value54", "value55", "value56", "value57", "value58", "value59", "value60", "value61", "value62", "value63", "value64", "value65", "value66", "value67", "value68", "value69", "value70", "value71", "value72", "value73", "value74", "value75", "value76", "value77", "value78", "value79", "value80", "value81", "value82", "value83", "value84", "value85", "value86", "value87", "value88", "value89", "value90", "value91", "value92", "value93", "value94", "value95", "value96", "value97", "value98", "value99", "value100", "value101", "value102", "value103", "value104", "value105", "value106", "value107", "value108", "value109", "value110", "value111", "value112", "value113", "value114", "value115", "value116", "value117", "value118", "value119", "value120", "value121", "value122", "value123", "value124", "value125", "value126", "value127", "value128", "value129", "value130", "value131", "value132", "value133", "value134", "value135", "value136", "value137", "value138", "value139", "value140", "value141", "value142", "value143", "value144", "value145", "value146", "value147", "value148", "value149", "value150", "value151", "value152", "value153", "value154", "value155", "value156", "value157", "value158", "value159", "value160", "value161", "value162", "value163", "value164", "value165", "value166", "value167", "value168", "value169", "value170", "value171", "value172", "value173", "value174", "value175", "value176", "value177", "value178", "value179", "value180", "value181", "value182", "value183", "value184", "value185", "value186", "value187", "value188", "value189", "value190", "value191", "value192", "value193", "value194", "value195", "value196", "value197", "value198", "value199", "value200", "value201", "value202", "value203", "value204", "value205", "value206", "value207", "value208", "value209", "value210", "value211", "value212", "value213", "value214", "value215", "value216", "value217", "value218", "value219", "value220", "value221", "value222", "value223", "value224", "value225", "value226", "value227", "value228", "value229", "value230", "value231", "value232", "value233", "value234", "value235", "value236", "value237", "value238", "value239", "value240", "value241", "value242", "value243", "value244", "value245", "value246", "value247", "value248", "value249", "value250", "value251", "value252", "value253", "value254", "value255", "value256", "value257", "value258", "value259", "value260", "value261", "value262", "value263", "value264", "value265", "value266", "value267", "value268", "value269", "value270", "value271", "value272", "value273", "value274", "value275", "value276", "value277", "value278", "value279", "value280", "value281", "value282", "value283", "value284", "value285", "value286", "value287", "value288", "value289", "value290", "value291", "value292", "value293", "value294", "value295", "value296", "value297", "value298", "value299", "value300", "value301", "value302", "value303", "value304", "value305", "value306", "value307", "value308", "value309", "value310", "value311", "value312", "value313", "value314", "value315", "value316", "value317", "value318", "value319", "value320", "value321", "value322", "value323", "value324", "value325", "value326", "value327", "value328", "value329", "value330", "value331", "value332", "value333", "value334", "value335", "value336", "value337", "value338", "value339", "value340", "value341", "value342", "value343", "value344", "value345", "value346", "value347", "value348", "value349")

 vector2 <- c("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6", "value7", "value8", "value9", "value10", "value11", "value12", "value13", "value14", "value15", "value16", "value17", "value18", "value19", "value20", "value21", "value22", "value23", "value24", "value25", "value26", "value27", "value28", "value29", "value30", "value31", "value32", "value33", "value34", "value35", "value36", "value37", "value38", "value39", "value40", "value41", "value42", "value43", "value44", "value45", "value46", "value47", "value48", "value49", "value50", "value51", "value52", "value53", "value54", "value55", "value56", "value57", "value58", "value59", "value60", "value61", "value62", "value63", "value64", "value65", "value66", "value67", "value68", "value69", "value70", "value71", "value72", "value73", "value74", "value75", "value76", "value77", "value78", "value79", "value80", "value81", "value82", "value83", "value84", "value85", "value86", "value87", "value88", "value89", "value90", "value91", "value92", "value93", "value94", "value95", "value96", "value97", "value98", "value99", "value100", "value101", "value102", "value103", "value104", "value105", "value106", "value107", "value108", "value109", "value110", "value111", "value112", "value113", "value114", "value115", "value116", "value117", "value118", "value119", "value120", "value121", "value122", "value123", "value124", "value125", "value126", "value127", "value128", "value129", "value130", "value131", "value132", "value133", "value134", "value135", "value136", "value137", "value138", "value139", "value140", "value141", "value142", "value143", "value144", "value145", "value146", "value147", "value148", "value149", "value150", "value151", "value152", "value153", "value154", "value155", "value156", "value157", "value158", "value159", "value160", "value161", "value162", "value163", "value164", "value165", "value166", "value167", "value168", "value169", "value170", "value171", "value172", "value173", "value174", "value175", "value176", "value177", "value178", "value179", "value180", "value181", "value182", "value183", "value184", "value185", "value186", "value187", "value188", "value189", "value190", "value191", "value192", "value193", "value194", "value195", "value196", "value197", "value198", "value199", "value200", "value201", "value202", "value203", "value204", "value205", "value206", "value207", "value208", "value209", "value210", "value211", "value212", "value213", "value214", "value215", "value216", "value217", "value218", "value219", "value220", "value221", "value222", "value223", "value224", "value225", "value226", "value227", "value228", "value229", "value230", "value231", "value232", "value233", "value234", "value235", "value236", "value237", "value238", "value239", "value240", "value241", "value242", "value243", "value244", "value245", "value246", "value247", "value248", "value249", "value250", "value251", "value252", "value253", "value254", "value255", "value256", "value257", "value258", "value259", "value260", "value261", "value262", "value263", "value264", "value265", "value266", "value267", "value268", "value269", "value270", "value271", "value272", "value273", "value274", "value275", "value276", "value277", "value278", "value279", "value280", "value281", "value282", "value283", "value284", "value285", "value286", "value287", "value288", "value289", "value290", "value291", "value292", "value293", "value294", "value295", "value296", "value297", "value298", "value299", "value300", "value301", "value302", "value303", "value304", "value305", "value306", "value307", "value308", "value309", "value310", "value311", "value312", "value313", "value314", "value315", "value316", "value317", "value318", "value319", "value320", "value321", "value322", "value323", "value324", "value325", "value326", "value327", "value328", "value329", "value330", "value331", "value332", "value333", "value334", "value335", "value336", "value337", "value338", "value339", "value340", "value341", "value342", "value343", "value344", "value345", "value346", "value347", "value348", "value349", "value350")
```

Comment: `x <- paste0("value", 1:350)` :)

Comment: Thank you. I like your suggestion. Works for this example, but not for my real data :) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Command lines entered at the console are limited to about 4095 bytes (not characters).

Source: [R Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc)

You can try it yourself, if you insert a line break, it will work:

```
vector2 <- c("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6", "value7", "value8", "value9", "value10", "value11", "value12", "value13", "value14", "value15", "value16", "value17", "value18", "value19", "value20", "value21", "value22", "value23", "value24", "value25", "value26", "value27", "value28", "value29", "value30", "value31", "value32", "value33", "value34", "value35", "value36", "value37", "value38", "value39", "value40", "value41", "value42", "value43", "value44", "value45", "value46", "value47", "value48", "value49", "value50", "value51", "value52", "value53", "value54", "value55", "value56", "value57", "value58", "value59", "value60", "value61", "value62", "value63", "value64", "value65", "value66", "value67", "value68", "value69", "value70", "value71", "value72", "value73", "value74", "value75", "value76", "value77", "value78", "value79", "value80", "value81", "value82", "value83", "value84", "value85", "value86", "value87", "value88", "value89", "value90", "value91", "value92", "value93", "value94", "value95", "value96", "value97", "value98", "value99", "value100", "value101", "value102", "value103", "value104", "value105", "value106", "value107", "value108", "value109", "value110", "value111", "value112", "value113", "value114", "value115", "value116", "value117", "value118", "value119", "value120", "value121", "value122", "value123", "value124", "value125", "value126", "value127", "value128", "value129", "value130", "value131", "value132", "value133", "value134", "value135", "value136", "value137", "value138", "value139", "value140", "value141", "value142", "value143", "value144", "value145", "value146", "value147", "value148", "value149", "value150", "value151", "value152", "value153", "value154", "value155", "value156", "value157", "value158", "value159", "value160", "value161", "value162", "value163", "value164", "value165", "value166", "value167", "value168", "value169", "value170", "value171", "value172", "value173", "value174", "value175", "value176", "value177", "value178", "value179", "value180", "value181", "value182", "value183", "value184", "value185", "value186", "value187", "value188", "value189", "value190", "value191", "value192", "value193", "value194", "value195", "value196", "value197", "value198", "value199", "value200", "value201", "value202", "value203", "value204", "value205", "value206", "value207", "value208", "value209", "value210", "value211", "value212", "value213", "value214", "value215", "value216", "value217", "value218", "value219", "value220", "value221", "value222", "value223", "value224", "value225", "value226", "value227", "value228", "value229", "value230", "value231", "value232", "value233", "value234", "value235", "value236", "value237", "value238", "value239", "value240", "value241", "value242", "value243", "value244", "value245", "value246", "value247", "value248", "value249", "value250", "value251", "value252", "value253", "value254", "value255", "value256", "value257", "value258", "value259", "value260", "value261", "value262", "value263", "value264", "value265", "value266", "value267", "value268", "value269", "value270", "value271", "value272", "value273", "value274", "value275", "value276", "value277", "value278", "value279", "value280", "value281", "value282", "value283", "value284", "value285", "value286", "value287", "value288", "value289", "value290", "value291", "value292", "value293", "value294", "value295", "value296", "value297", "value298", "value299", "value300", "value301", "value302", "value303", "value304", "value305", "value306", "value307", "value308", "value309", "value310", "value311", "value312", "value313", "value314", "value315", "value316", "value317", "value318", "value319", "value320", "value321", "value322", "value323", "value324", "value325", "value326", "value327", "value328", "value329", "value330", "value331", "value332", "value333", "value334", "value335", "value336", "value337", "value338", "value339", "value340", "value341", "value342", "value343", "value344", "value345", "value346", "value347", "value348", "value349",
             "value350")
```

Anyway, it is good practice to avoid long lines to increase code readability. Stick to 80 or 120 character long lines, e.g.:

```
vector2 <- c("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6", "value7",
             "value8", "value9", "value10", "value11", "value12", "value13",
             "value14", "value15", "value16", "value17", "value18", "value19",
             .
             .
             .
             "value344", "value345", "value346", "value347", "value348", "value349",
             "value350")
```

Comment: This is very cool! I had no idea. Thank you so much. Solves my problem! :)